# Wildfly 8.1.0 Final freezes (keeps connections forever / Channel was closed mid chunk)

Tags: ubuntu, networking, azure, jboss, wildfly8

I have just migrated an application from JBoss 7.1.1 to Wildfly 8.1.0 Final. But now from time to time (like every 2 days) Wildfly freezes, and I have to restart it. My application is basically EJB/JPA/JAX-RS w/ Resteasy.

By freezing I mean that every HTTP access to Wildfly keeps waiting forever. I suspect that only Undertow is frozen, because I can see in my application log that tasks that were scheduled are executing, although none of these are network related.

I also noticed in my log the following error: "Response is committed, can't handle exception" caused by IOException "Channel was closed mid chunk, if you have attempted to write chunked data you cannot shutdown the channel until after it has all been written".

Server is an Ubuntu VM running on Azure. "Physical memory" and "hard disk" space are fine. Heap, non-heap and thread usages are fine according to JVM Runtime in Wildfly Management.

Only thing I noticed is that I have many connections established forever when I "netstat -aln". I have fewer than 100 clients per day but right now I count 2K established connections on my port 8080.

What can I do to better diagnose and resolve this problem?

Best Regards,
Renan

*UPDATE*: it was indeed a bug on 8.1.0 fixed for 8.2.0, see my answer with link to issue opened at JbossDeveloper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug on 8.1.0 fixed for 8.2.0:

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-3536?_sscc=t

Answer (score 2):

I would like to share my experience as a developer/architect on Wildfly 8.1

I migrate from 7.1.1 to 8.1 on Windows/Eclipse a few day ago.
I also noticed some instabilities; a member of the developement team did the migration, and complains about eclipse crashes / not the same behaviour as 7.1.1. An other team member is still working on Wildfly 8.0; it seems that previous version is more stable.

JBOss would tell you that Wildfly is not a production app server; it is for development purpose. But I think that you are pointing to some serious bug / converging with my sucpicions / without any real facts, and no answer to your question.

You should forward your post directly to the JBoss forums in order to be shure that the Wildfly team investigate the problem and hope that the the fix will be part of 8.2 releases.

Comment: I posted the issue on the Wildfly forum and they replied saying this is probably a bug. I'll open a ticket for this issue in their bug tracking system, and when I have news I'll post here as well.

By the way, I also use Wildows/Eclipse/Wildfly but didn't notice Eclipse crashes (I am using Kepler SR2).

Best regards,
Renan

Comment: OK / it isn't Eclise itself, but JBoss inside Eclise. Though developement is using massively hotdebug on different interconnected wars, and this is subjet to turn the server into instable, it appears that JBoss AS was 'more (?) stable on previous versions : 7.1.1 and 8.0.

Comment: OK, now I understood your problem. I avoid using hotdebug because it is so instable that I gave up this feature.

Comment: When the developper explained me that 'regression' I was amazed how massively he is using hotdebugging; frankly I even didn't know that it was possible to let a server runnning with a 3 -wars application within Eclipse and developping a few hours hotdebbuging (Vaadin Framework) without having to stop / start explicitely the server. Now it seems that it is 'less' stable / though hotdebug is still OK.

Answer (score 0):

I was using wildfly 8.0 final with With Spring 4.1.0 and JSF 2.0 & JDK 8.0_u25
I was facing same Exception:
  **UT005013: An IOException occurred: java.io.IOException: UT000029: Channel was closed mid chunk, if you  have attempted to write chunked data you cannot shutdown the channel until after it has all been written.**

And my Server CPU Processing increase 25% of each time of exception occurrence.
Alhumdulillah Now I Resolve my problem.

Now I'm using:
Wildfly 8.2.0 Final With Spring 4.1.0 and JSF 2.0 & JDK 8.0_u25

Wildfly 8.2.0 resolve my CPU Processing issue
I observe my server almost 8 days then I realize that when host(Client/User) send some request to server that required some time for calculating/ Server Response time at that user close his browser window or log-out before getting response from server. when Server done his processing and then try to send response to his specific Host/Client request then IO Exception occurs because client closed the browser window.

I Hope this will help you ou